# Why return type of findElement(By by) is WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Why return type of findElement(By by) is WebElement?**

I know it has  mention in documentation that return type is Webelment,But can anyone please explain  me why return type is Webelment.

**My research on this topic**.

Because we are searching elements using findElement and webelement class is used to represent HTML element.

Please let me know If I am thinking right or there any specific reason

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable that if you're trying to find an element, the return type would be an element. I'm interested in what provoked the question though - it sounds like you would expect it to have a *different* return type... what would you expect it to be, and why?

Comment: @Jon Skeet My thoughts were the return type might be Boolean,as we are searching  an element and might be as ,if found return true else false,

Comment: @SainathPawar Simply detecting whether an element is present or absent is not as flexible or powerful as what they give you. You can't `click` or `sendKeys` to a `boolean`. Not to mention testing if it's enabled, selected or displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw it right. As per the *Java Docs* [findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method returns a **Webelment**.

To answer your question *why return type is Webelment* a counter question to you would be **Why are you finding the element?**.

Of-coarse the answer is you need to **interact** (in some way) with the element which may be either of the following :

- Heading
- Text field
- Password field
- Button
- Select element
- etc

You are searching the *WebElement* as you either want to :

- Assert the WebElement condition (`isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled()`).
- Interact with it (`click()`, `sendKeys()`).
- Retrive any of its attributes. (`getAttribute()`, `getCssValue()`)
- Wait for the *WebElement* to be in certain condition (`isSelected()`).

So for either of those reasons you need to get the reference of the *WebElement* which you pass through **findElement(By by)** and if your search is successful the exact *WebElement* is returned back. Now you can invoke any of the enlisted [`methods()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) on the *WebElement* as per feasibility as follows :

- **`clear()`**
- **`click()`**
- **`findElement(By by)`**
- **`findElements(By by)`**
- **`getAttribute(java.lang.String name)`**
- **`getCssValue(java.lang.String propertyName)`**
- **`getLocation()`**
- **`getSize()`**
- **`getTagName()`**
- **`getText()`**
- **`isDisplayed()`**
- **`isEnabled()`**
- **`isSelected()`**
- **`sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)`**
- **`submit()`**

Invoking any of the following `methods()` wouldn't have been possible if the return type of **findElement()** had been **Boolean** (as per your comment update).