# What is the difference between WebDriver and WebElement in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the difference between WebDriver and WebElement in Selenium?

Sample Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();      
driver.get("http://www.google.com");      
WebElement s  = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));      
s.sendKeys("Packt Publishing");      
s.submit();
```

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?  They're entirely different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### WebDriver Interface

From [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s perspective, the [What is the difference between ChromeDriver and WebDriver in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) *interface* is similar like a agreement which the 3rd party *Browser Vendors* like *Mozilla*, *Chrome*, *Internet Explorer*, *Safari*, etc have to adhere and implement the same. This would in-turn help the end-users to use the exposed APIs to write a common code and implement the functionalities across all the available browsers without any change.

---

### WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Through the line of code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

We are creating an instance of the *WebDriver Interface* and **casting** it to *FirefoxDriver* class. All the *Browser Drivers* like [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html), [ChromeDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html), [InternetExplorerDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html), [PhantomJSDriver](http://phantomjs.org/), [SafariDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariDriver.html) etc implemented the [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface (actually the [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) class implements *WebDriver Interface* and the *browser drivers* extends *RemoteWebDriver*). So if we use `WebDriver driver`, then we can use the already initialized *driver* instance (as common object variable) for all browsers we want to automate e.g. Mozilla, Chrome, InternetExplorer, PhantomJS, Safari.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new SafariDriver();
```

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Is this correct - FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996626/is-this-correct-firefoxdriver-driver-new-firefoxdriver)
- [what is the difference between ChromeDriver and WebDriver in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium)

---

### WebElement Interface

From *Selenium* perspective, [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) represents an HTML element. Generally, all the operations to do with interacting with a page will be performed through this interface.

A *WebElement* is an abstraction used to identify the [Element nodes and are simply known as elements](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element) when it is transported via the protocol, between remote and local ends. The web element identifier is the string constant expressed as:

```
"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf"
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Values returned by webdrivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369301/values-returned-by-webdrivers)

Each element has an associated web element reference that uniquely identifies the element across all browsing contexts. The web element reference for every element representing the same element must be the same. It must be a string, and should be the result of generating a UUID.

An ECMAScript [Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1) represents a web element if it has a web element identifier own property.

Each browsing context has an associated list of known elements. When the browsing context is discarded, the list of known elements is discarded along with it.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Why return type of findElement(By by) is WebElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340333/why-return-type-of-findelementby-by-is-webelement)

Some of the commonly used associated methods are as follows:

- `clear()`
- `click()`
- `findElement(By by)`
- `findElements(By by)`
- `getAttribute(java.lang.String name)`
- `getCssValue(java.lang.String propertyName)`
- `getLocation()`
- `getRect()`
- `getSize()`
- `getTagName()`
- `getText()`
- `isDisplayed()`
- `isEnabled()`
- `isSelected()`
- `sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)`
- `submit()`

Answer (score 0):

The **WebDriver** class focuses on driving the browser in a **broad** sense. It loads pages, it switches to different windows/frames, gets the page title etc.  Broad actions that aren't specific to an element on the page.

**WebElement** concentrates on interacting with a **specific** element that you've located.  Things like:

- Clicking that specific element
- Retrieving text and other values from that specific element
- Finding out where that specific element is positioned
- Sending text to that specific element (like filling an input field)

The only real overlap between WebDriver and WebElement are the findElement and findElements methods. For **Webdriver**, these methods locate the given By anywhere on the page.  For **WebElement** these methods locate the given By within the context of that element (inside it, generally).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

- The **WebDriver** focuses on manipulating the browser.
- The **WebElement** is just an Document element object like
  `<button></button>`